# Complex layout of multiple components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, miglayout

I am designing a GUI where I have the components shown below. But in the second row, I would like to manage spaces between the components. For example, in the second row, I would like to fit both the `JLabel` "Move to time" and the `JTextField` without so much spacing. As I can see, right now `MigLayout` places the `JTextField` in line with the second component in the first row. Then, the `JButton` "Move" in the 2nd row should be aligned to the 2nd component in the first row. How do I achieve this? Below is my code. I looked up many cheat sheets and quick start guides on `MigLayout` but I couldn't manage yet. Can somebody recommend changes in my code snippet? Thank you.

`

```
    JPanel helper = new JPanel( new MigLayout( "" ) );
    helper.add( new JButton( "Add puncta coordinates from CSV" ), "width 250:20" );
    helper.add( new JButton( "Add track coordinates from CSV" ), "wrap" );
    helper.add( new JLabel( "Move to time:" ) );
    JTextField tMoveTime = new JTextField();
    helper.add( tMoveTime, " gap 2px, width 75:20" );
    JButton bMoveTime = initMoveButton();
    helper.add( bMoveTime, "width 75:20" );
```

`

[image]

Actually, I intend to make the following GUI in full with all buttons and textfields, is any other layout more suited? If yes, can an example code snippet for the recommended layout be pointed to? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be `MigLayout` ?

Comment: @c0der No, it doesn't have to be, but in fact I started with MigLayout. Actually, I am trying to make the full GUI with all the buttons and fields (question updated and full GUI picture posted). I started with MigLayout, what can you recommend? Also can you please post some helpful code snippet for the recommended Layout? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider two basic approaches : 
One is to use highly flexible layout manager, like `MigLayout`. I am not familiar with it, but I can recommend [GridbagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for the job:

```
    JPanel helper = new JPanel(  );
    GridBagLayout gbl_helper = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_helper.columnWidths = new int[]{200, 7, 200, 60, 18, 0};
    gbl_helper.rowHeights = new int[]{20, 20};
    gbl_helper.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_helper.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0};
    helper.setLayout(gbl_helper);

    GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc1.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gbc1.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    gbc1.gridx = 0;
    gbc1.gridy = 0;
    JButton button1 = new JButton( "Add puncta coordinates from CSV" );
    helper.add( button1, gbc1 );

    GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc2.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc2.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gbc2.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    gbc2.gridx = 2;
    gbc2.gridy = 0;
    JButton button2 = new JButton( "Add track coordinates from CSV" );

    helper.add( button2, gbc2 );

    GridBagConstraints gbc3 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc3.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc3.gridx = 0;
    gbc3.gridy = 1;
    JLabel label = new JLabel( "Move to time:" );
    helper.add( label, gbc3 );

    JTextField tMoveTime = new JTextField();
    tMoveTime.setColumns(15);
    GridBagConstraints gbc4 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc4.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc4.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc4.gridx = 1;
    gbc4.gridy = 1;
    helper.add( tMoveTime, gbc4);

    JButton bMoveTime = new JButton("Move");
    GridBagConstraints gbc5 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc5.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc5.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
    gbc5.gridx = 3;
    gbc5.gridy = 1;
    helper.add( bMoveTime, gbc5 );
```

[image]

A different approach is to divide a complex layout to simpler layouts by using sub - panels, each with it's own layout manager:

[image]

```
    JPanel helper = new JPanel(  );
    helper.setLayout(new BoxLayout(helper, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    getContentPane().add(helper);

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    helper.add(topPanel);
    JButton button1 = new JButton( "Add puncta coordinates from CSV" );
    topPanel.add(button1);
    JButton button2 = new JButton( "Add track coordinates from CSV" );
    topPanel.add(button2);

    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    helper.add(bottomPanel);
    bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    JPanel bottomRIght = new JPanel();
    bottomPanel.add(bottomRIght);
    JLabel label = new JLabel( "Move to time:" );
    bottomRIght.add(label);
    JTextField tMoveTime = new JTextField();
    bottomRIght.add(tMoveTime);
    tMoveTime.setColumns(15);

    JPanel bottomleftPanel = new JPanel();
    bottomPanel.add(bottomleftPanel);
    bottomleftPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 5));
    JButton bMoveTime = new JButton("Move");
    bottomleftPanel.add(bMoveTime);
```

[image]